# TypeError: Key must be a buffer when sending an email with aws-sdk in node.js

Tags: node.js, config, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, node-config

I'm trying to set up an emailing system with `nodemailer` that's agnostic of the transport type it uses.

Here's how I'm trying to send the email:

```
const config = require('config')
const mailerConfig = config.get('mailer')
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailerConfig.transport)
transporter.sendMail({
  from: mailerConfig.from,
  to: toEmail,
  subject,
  text: textBody,
  html: htmlBody,
})
```

And here's how my `config` file looks like:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
module.exports = {
  mailer: {
    from: 'test_sender@domain.com',
    transport: {
      SES: new AWS.SES({
        accessKeyId: 'secret-key',
        secretAccessKey: 'access-key',
        region: 'region',
      }),
    },
  }
}
```

Then, whenever I try to send an email, I get the following error:

```
error:  TypeError: Key must be a buffer
    at new Hmac (crypto.js:117:16)
    at Object.Hmac (crypto.js:115:12)
    at Object.hmac (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:401:30)
    at Object.getSigningKey (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4_credentials.js:59:8)
at V4.signature (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4.js:97:36)
at V4.authorization (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4.js:92:36)
at V4.addAuthorization (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4.js:34:12)
at /Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:215:18
at finish (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:320:7)
at /Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:338:9
at /Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:123:23
at Credentials.refresh (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:194:5)
at Credentials.get (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:121:12)
at getAsyncCredentials (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:332:24)
at Config.getCredentials (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:352:9)
at Request.SIGN (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:192:22)
```

Please note that when I'm instantiating `AWS.SES()` in the same place where I'm sending the email, the code works fine. Is there anything special that `config` does to break the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything special that config does to break the code?

Exactly. `config` package deep-merges all configs. So it walks thru your config, and breaks object returned from `AWS.SES()`. You can try to put your keys in config, and apply them to `ses` only on usage:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
module.exports = {
  mailer: {
    from: 'test_sender@domain.com',
    transport: {
      SES: {
        accessKeyId: 'secret-key',
        secretAccessKey: 'access-key',
        region: 'region',
      },
    },
  }
}
```

And use it:

```
const config = require('config')
const mailerConfig = config.get('mailer')
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: new AWS.SES(mailerConfig.transport.SES)
})
transporter.sendMail({
  from: mailerConfig.from,
  to: toEmail,
  subject,
  text: textBody,
  html: htmlBody,
})
```

---

As alternative you can require your config file directly:

```
const config = require('./config') // depends on your files structure
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've mentioned in my question that instantiating SES when I'm actually using it works fine :( But what I'm trying to do is to setup a mailing function that can be easily configured to use a different transport. So you're saying that `config` somehow breaks the AWS.SES object and that there's no way around that? :(

Comment: I think, it's either bug in `config` package or the way it should work, with simple objects only

Answer (score 1):

In my case accessKey and secretAccessKey was undefined.

Comment: same in my case, but its very odd. `process.env.AWS_REGION` prints out properly, but `process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `process.env.AWS_SECRET` print undefined. spelling and everything is correct. This is in Lambda btw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the maintainers of `node-config`. It sounds like it may be an issue that `node-config` has added some methods to your configuration object when you just want the plain data back.

[Since v1.27.0](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/pull/438), `config.util.toObject(someValue)` was added to allow you to get back a plain old JavaScript object for a given config value. It's documented on our [utils wiki page](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Using-Config-Utilities#toobjectconfig)

If you have an older version of `node-config` and don't want to upgrade, you also do this on a config structure returned by`node-config`:

```
var plainOldValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(configValue)
```

That has the effect of removing the methods added by `node-config` and is exactly what the new `.toObject()` method does internally.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I've tried both methods you suggested but the SES object still seems to be broken: 
`TypeError: this.ses.sendRawEmail is not a function`

Comment: I've also tried the `cloneDeep` util function and it seems to do a better job at cloning the SES object but I still get an error: 
`error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at ucfirst (/Users/sebi/Work/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/query/query_param_serializer.js:11:38)`